# Accessing repeated XML tags at differing hierarchy levels in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML file which uses the following hierarchy structure;

```
    item
        item
            (item details)
        item
            (item details)
    item
        item
            (item details)
        item
            (item details)
        item
            (item details)
```

etc..

I want to be able to access each of the 'item' tags at the first level, and for each of those, access the 'item's within that (second level) and assign its details (third levels) to an individual object for each second level item. I can search using jQuery for each item tag, however this obviously goes through 'item' tags at both levels, rather than just the first level.

How can I retrieve each first level item, and then use that as a reference to access the items within it (so each of the second level items are processed one at a time)?

Tried to word this as clearly as possible, I don't like the reuse of the "item" tag but it's out of my control sadly.. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not after a full solution to be given to me, just a pseudo-code style method of achieving this. I can obviously code this statically, looping through each item, but this relies on me knowing how many items there are at each level, which will change each time.. I have sat with pen and paper and tried to work this out, but I honestly have no idea where to start, and how to differentiate between each level

Comment: That's not the point. Showing what you've started with is an important indicator of your level of competence, which helps in producing a suitable answer.

Comment: Well I apologise, and i'll bear that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to do it the other way around:

- `$("item>item")` will give you access to the second level item tags only.
- for each second level item, use parent() to access the related first level item

You could also use `$("item")` to get all items, then use `$(this).find("item")` in a loop to get the second level items. If `$(this).find("item")` has a length of 0, it means that `this` is a second row item:

```
$("item").each(function(){
    var childrenItems=$(this).find("item");
    if (childrenItems.length) {
        // process the children items
    }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the logic i couldn't picture, and was more than I expected, thanks a lot.