# Getting two level of from xml (hierarchy data)

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml data a bit like this:

```
<pages>
  <page name=1>
    <page name=2>
        <page name=3>
            <page name=4>
            </page>
            <page name=5>
            </page>
        </page>
        <page name=6>
        </page>
    </page>
    <page name=12>
        <page name=3>
            <page name=4>
            </page>
            <page name=5>
            </page>
        </page>
        <page name=6>
        </page>
    </page>
  </page>
</page>
<page name = 13>
  <page name=11>
    <page name=2>
        <page name=3>
            <page name=4>
            </page>
            <page name=5>
            </page>
        </page>
        <page name=6>
        </page>
    </page>
  </page>
</pages>
```

I want to get the name of get the first two level of the name attribute to an array.

```
1,2,12,13,11
```

I tried this:

```
var results = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xx.xml",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (xml) {
            if (typeof xml == 'string' || xml instanceof String) {
                var $doc = $.parseXML(xml);

                $($doc).find('page').each(function(){
                    results.push($(this).attr('name'));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried this : [Accessing repeated XML tags at differing hierarchy levels in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232039/accessing-repeated-xml-tags-at-differing-hierarchy-levels-in-javascript) 
However, I find the `find()` function in jQuery get all the page;
I just want the first two level of the hierarchy tree.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

From a kind person in SO:

```
var results = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pathwayHierarchy.xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (xml) {
        if (typeof xml == 'string' || xml instanceof String) {
            var $doc = $.parseXML(xml);
            $($doc).find('pages').children().each(function(){
                results.push($(this).attr('name'));
                $(this).children().each(function(){
                    results.push($(this).attr('name'));
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I delete a comment, How can find who answered this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the requested results:

```
$($doc).find("pages > page, pages > page > page").each(function() {
   results.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

This is will find all page elements that are 1 or 2 tiers down.

Alternately, you could use children() as I suggested in a comment previously. But I prefer the single find.